# GridLayout in panel not showing buttons

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I created a class that extends `JPanel` called `GamePane` which on creation sets the layout to a `GridLayout` and then adds buttons one at a time:

```
public class GamePane extends JPanel {
    private JButton[][] buttons;
    private final int sizeX, sizeY;
    private Partida partida;

    public GamePane(int sizeX, int sizeY, Partida p) {
        super();
        this.sizeX = sizeX;
        this.sizeY = sizeY;
        this.partida = p;
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(sizeX + 1, sizeY + 1));
        buttons = new JButton[sizeX + 1][sizeY + 1];

        for (int y = 0; y < sizeY + 1; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeX + 1; x++) {
                JButton button = new JButton();
                button.addActionListener(new ListenerGameButton(x, y, this));
                this.add(button);
                button.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                button.setVisible(true);
                buttons[x][y] = button;
            }
        }
```

The panel initialization is done on the parent `JDialog`:

```
gamePane = new GamePane(sizeX, sizeY, parentPartida);
```

And here's how it looks in the NetBeans editor: (The selected frame being an instance of `GamePane`)
[image]

Then when testing it out it doesn't show the buttons:
[image]

This is the class of the parent JDialog where the child GamePane is located, most of the code is autogenerated by Netbeans:

```
public class gameDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

private final int sizeX, sizeY;
private Partida parentPartida;

public gameDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, int sizeX, int sizeY, Partida parentPartida)
{
    super(parent, modal);
    this.parentPartida = parentPartida;
    this.sizeX = sizeX;
    this.sizeY = sizeY;
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    logoPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    gamePane = new GamePane(sizeX, sizeY, parentPartida);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Partida en curso");
    setModal(true);
    setResizable(false);

    logoPane.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(95, 143, 191));

    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/GUI/logo.png"))); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED, new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
    jLabel1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout logoPaneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(logoPane);
    logoPane.setLayout(logoPaneLayout);
    logoPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        logoPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    logoPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        logoPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 149, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout gamePaneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(gamePane);
    gamePane.setLayout(gamePaneLayout);
    gamePaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        gamePaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 437, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    gamePaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        gamePaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 353, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(gamePane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(logoPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(logoPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(gamePane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private GUI.GamePane gamePane;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel logoPane;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

The initComponents() method is generated by NetBeans and that's where the GamePane is created and later on the frame is packed at the end of initComponents() by calling pack()
So, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: but do you add the gamePane itself to something?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino I added the GamePane using the netbeans swing editor, I can include the netbeans generated code if necessary.

Comment: Why do you specify array sizes as "sizeX+1" and "sizeY+1"?  Why set sizeX=6 in order to get 7 buttons?

Comment: That's simply because sizeX and sizeY represent the size of the board, and an extra row and column is added to later create fake buttons that only display row and column number

Comment: Your edit adds nothing to your question, please include an actual [mcve] - in other words add all the relevant code.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I understand your concern, but there's not actually much more except from the autogenerated code by Netbeans, I'll add that right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with your code. It is perfectly working fine.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.getContentPane().add(new GamePane(10, 10));
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

And i got the below.

[image]

Comment: Alright, believe it or not, your answer made me look into the code generated by netbeans and realized that's where the problem lies. I set the layout on the GamePane constructor, and then netbeans replaced it with the default one, so I simply created the buttons after all the netbeans code

Comment: I was just about to type that. Anyways have a great day.

Comment: @Chapi: and we're supposed to guess that was the reason, how? In the future, please post **all** relevant code, preferably as a [mcve] and not as a link.